# Can residual connection affect the learning of skipped layers?

Tags: neural-networks, residual-networks

My understanding of residual connection is it could help avoid degradation by making $F(x)$, the skipped layers, close to 0 so that when $F(x)$ become redundant it won't hurt the performance. What make me confused is how can the model figure out whether to learn from these layers or really skip them?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of residual connections is to avoid vanishing gradients. The gradients will be computed by backpropagating through both paths, i.e. through the weight layers, but also through the shortcut, ensuring the gradients are not getting smaller and smaller with more layers. So yes, the two intermediate layers in your figure are also learned, they are not actually skipped.

Comment: Be careful -- the authors of ResNet say the "optimization difficulty [which resnets purports to solve] is **unlikely to be caused by vanishing gradients**" emphasis mine.